# Is WCF a good fit for this problem?

Tags: .net, wcf, soap

I'm working to implement a data service solution that has 2 request functions but can respond with one of 3 transmission types:

1. x12 EDI
2. HTTP MIME multipart
3. SOAP/XML + WSDL

I would also need to include logging and username/password authentication to the services. I'm in the very early learning stages of WCF. Is WCF a good fit for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, WCF is a good fit for this.  It supports everything in your list.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out FubuMVC too - at my previous job we implemented something pretty similar over that stack; it has really powerful composability, which means that you can conditionally add behaviors like logging/auditing/authentication and adding a formatter to format the output correctly is simply a matter of putting the behavior into the behavior chain. It's also convention driven, so it's very flexible.

All of that said, I can say that WCF Data Services specifically isn't the right solution (one of your tags) but WCF would probably meet your needs and comes with a better support agreement than FubuMVC.